# Is $XY$ independent of $X$ and $Y$?

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, random-variables, independence

Let $X, Y:\ \Omega \mapsto \{-1,1\}$ be two independent random variables such that

$$P(X=\pm 1)=P(Y=\pm 1)=1/2.$$

Let $Z=XY$. Based on how I have reasoned so far, I can tell that $X$ is independent of $Z$ and $Y$ is also independent of $Z$. However, I am not completely sure. Is the following proof correct?

For all $a,b \in \Omega$, we have

$$P(X=a,Z=b)=P(X=a,Y=ab)=P(X=a)P(Y=ab)=1/4=P(X=a)P(Z=b),$$

and in the same way, we can show the independence of $Y$ and $Z$.

Comment: Careful with your wording.  It is true that $XY$ is independent of $X$, and that $XY$ is independent of $Y$.  When you say "$XY$ is independent of $X$ and $Y$", it can be interpreted as "$XY$ is independent of the pair $(X,Y)$" which is not true.

Comment: @StubbornAtom By assumption, $a,b\in\{-1,1\}$, which means that division is always possible and amounts to the same as multiplication.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for your correction. You are totally right. I just edited it. So the proof is correct?

Comment: Yes, the proof is correct.